# WCF - All possible Web Service Exceptions that can be thrown

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I am trying to cover all exceptions that a WCF webservice can throw.

I have seen this code which is what is I was envisioning

```
try
{

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     switch (ex.GetType().ToString())
     {
         case "System.InvalidOperationException":
              //cast ex to specific type of exception to use it's properties
              ((InvalidOperationException)ex).SomeMethod();
         break;
         case "System.NotSupportedException":
             ((System.NotSupportedException)ex).AnotherMethod();
         break;
         case "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException":
             ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException)ex).OtherMethod();
         break;
     }

}
```

I am just wondering if there any more exceptions that a WCF webservice can throw?

Are there any links I can read? (I dont particularly like the answer given to me if possible)

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to WCF -- you can have multiple `catch` blocks, one for each type. You should not be switching on the type's name.

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to paste that code to provide more information to the readers of what I wanted